# How to refresh a connection with NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, nsurlconnection

I'm working on a project for school, and I was wondering if there was a way to actually update the connection with NSURLConnection if a user submits something.  For example, I'm having twitter search based on username, and I have a default username set up when the view loads.  What would I have to do to refresh that connection when a user enters a different username on that page?  I have my button handlers all set up, and I'm using the same code as in my viewDidLoad function.  Is there a method call or something that will actually reset the connection?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attached example codes

```
// member variable 'conn'
// NSURLConnection *conn;
// @property(strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *conn;
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self sendRequest];
}
- (IBAction)sendButtonClicked {
  [self sendRequest];
}
- (void)sendRequest {
  if (self.conn) {
    [self.conn cancel];
    self.conn = nil;
  }
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.conn = conn;
    [conn start];

} 
// NSURLConnection Delegates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
   // append received data
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
   // error handling
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
   // using data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I canceled the old connection on my button press, nil'd out the request and connection, and started it up again, but it still isn't working.

Comment: I actually figured out where in the code it's not working at.  The parser I set up at the end of the connectionDidFinishLoading isn't actually launching.

Comment: It runs the first time, but not the subsequent times when the button is pressed

Comment: I thought that problem with [NSURLRequest CachePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) in [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I tried changing the cache policy to have it not cache, but that still didn't fix the issue.  I'm doing more research though.  THank you for the help c:

Answer (score 0):

---

I don't think you can "reset" the connection. You will have to make a new request. In your button clicked method simply make a new request call with the new user name. 
It works like a request in a browser, when you change some parameter in the url the browser sends of a new request to the web-server.

have a look at this example by apple (if you dont need the caching part just focus on URLCacheConnection.h/.m) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/URLCache/Listings/Classes_URLCacheController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008061-Classes_URLCacheController_m-DontLinkElementID_10
i

Comment: Nanako, 

Thanks for taking a look at it.  I have my button press to nil out the old request and connection, and establish new ones.  It also reparses and reloads the table view I'm using, but it still never actually initiates the new connection.  =/